# Searching DevExpress TreeListView with more than a million items

Tags: c#, wpf, full-text-search, devexpress-wpf, treelistview

I am building a TreeListView (DevExpress) with more than 5 million rows. (Around 15 million rows)

I wonder how should the searching work in that case as the user won't be expanding all the branches for searching. And the existing search in TreeListView allows the search only if the nodes have been expanded.

Also,
Should I search it on my datasource or should I search it in the TreeListView control?

Also, if we we use paging and dynamic loading for loading the items, it's possible to search through the data source but how can I show the results in the TreeListView?

Comment: Have you *tried* any of those approaches?

Comment: "Should I search it on my datasource or should I search it in the TreeListView control?" If I as a user were confronted with even one million rows in a treeview I would be **slightly** over burdened.... and probably close this application. Why do you see the need to display all the data at once? Do you want to allow the user for a manual search in `5000000` rows by scrolling?

Comment: @Fildor , yes I have tried to search it in the TreeListView.

Comment: @MongZhu , I am providing searching through a search box at the top of tree.

Comment: how does you searching work? do you want to display the search results in the TreeListView? If YES, why do you want to display the entire 5000000 items tree in the first place? and Yes I would search in the data source

Comment: It's not necessary to display all the 5m items in the first place. It can be loaded dynamically when expanding the parent node.
And the search results should be displayed in the TreeListView. @MongZhu

Comment: Also, if we we use paging and dynamic loading for loading the items, it's possible to search through the data source but how can I show the results in the TreeListView?

Comment: have a second data source which will contain only the search results, then hook the second data source to the TreeListView after a sucessfull search

Answer (score 0):

> the existing search in TreeListView allows the search only if the nodes have been expanded

This is not correct. Set the TreeListView.ExpandNodesOnFiltering-property to true
and set the TreeListView.FilterMode to either Smart or Extended.

I never had problems with searching in the GridControl and I doubt that you'll be able to create a faster search-mechanism yourself ;)